# Find indices of values in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find the indices of the integers in a list. I have a following code that works but it takes over 45 seconds. Is there a faster way that I can use? My code looks like following:

```
for i in range(0,len(output)) :
    indexes = [ii for ii,x in enumerate(Node1ID) if x == i].
```

Comment: Show us some inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unnecessarily iterating through the `Node1ID` list over and over again for `len(output)` times, each time incrementing the integer you're looking for. You should instead produce a dict of lists where the integer you're looking for is the index and the matching indices are in the corresponding sub-list:

```
indexes = {}
for i, x in enumerate(Node1ID):
    indexes.setdefault(x, []).append(i)
```

so that you can look up the list of matching indices of an integer `i` with:

```
indexes.get(i, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using numpy:

```
# Get all the numbers to match (in this case len(output) = 10)
y = np.arange(10)

# Example array
x = [1,1,5,3,11]

y_indices, x_indices = np.where(x == y[:,None])
print(y_indices)
# array([1, 1, 3, 5])
print(x_indices)
# array([0, 1, 3, 2])
```

The output is interpreted as `x[0] == 1`, `x[1] == 1`, `x[3] == 3`, `x[2] == 5`